# Why does not my QString get the value of the TextField?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5, qobject

I'm trying to pass the value of the TextField to a String, I believe the Source is correct, but when I insert the "value" into the TextField and click on the button, it returns nothing, but if I set this value in 
TextField {Text:"Example"}, it returns: "Example", any ideas?

FirstPage.qml

```
Item {

Rectangle {
    anchors.fill: parent

    ColumnLayout {
        id: layoutLogin
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        anchors.margins: 3
        spacing: 3

        TextField {
            objectName: "login"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            placeholderText: "Username"
        }

        TextField {
            property string password: text
            objectName: "passwordd"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            placeholderText: "Password"
            echoMode: TextInput.Password
        }

        Button {
            id: proccessButton
            text: "Login"
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            onClicked: Login.test()
        }
      }
   }
}
```

login.cpp:

```
Login::Login() {
QQuickView view;
view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/FirstPage.qml")));
QObject *object = view.rootObject();
QObject *login = object->findChild<QObject*>("login");
QObject *password = object->findChild<QObject*>("password");
login_u = login->property("login").toString();
password_u = password->property("password").toString();}

void Login::test(){
    qDebug() << "user:" << login_u;
    qDebug() << "password" << password_u;
}
```

Output when i Click in the "Button":

```
user: ""
password ""
```

Comment: Where do you trigger the `Login` constructor, to retrieve the values? Shouldn't that be done in the `test()` action?

Comment: You can place a reproducible code, you have eliminated some details that are important.

Comment: i try @user0042 , same result.

Comment: @CésarAugusto Try your solution and if you have any questions tell me so I can help you

Comment: For the password field there's a a typo in the `objectName`: `objectName: "passwordd"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will go a little deeper trying to solve the background problem which is how to get the QML data from C ++ correctly.

The first task is to implement a class that inherits from `QObject` and handle the username and password properties as shown below:

In this class we must expose the properties using the `Q_PROPERTY` macro, and if we want a function to be called from QML, it must be preceded by `Q_INVOKABLE`.

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QObject>

#include <QDebug>

class Login : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString username READ username WRITE setUsername NOTIFY usernameChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString password READ password WRITE setPassword NOTIFY passwordChanged)
public:
    explicit Login(QObject *parent = nullptr):QObject(parent){

    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void test(){
        qDebug()<<mUsername<<mPassword;
    }

    QString username() const{
        return mUsername;
    }

    void setUsername(const QString &username){
        if(mUsername == username)
            return;
        mUsername = username;
        emit usernameChanged(mUsername);
    }


    QString password() const{
        return mPassword;
    }

    void setPassword(const QString &password)
    {
        if(mPassword == password)
            return;
        mPassword = password;
        emit passwordChanged(mPassword);
    }

signals:
    void usernameChanged(QString username);
    void passwordChanged(QString password);
private:
    QString mUsername;
    QString mPassword;
};


#endif // LOGIN_H
```

Then we register it next to QML using qmlRegisterType so now this is a QML library

```
#include "login.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<Login>("com.examples.login", 1, 0, "Login");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
        return -1;

    return app.exec();
}
```

And in the end we use them on the qml side assigning the corresponding connections

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import com.examples.login 1.0

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Login")

    Login{
        id: login
        username: usernameField.text
        password: passwordField.text          
    }

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ColumnLayout {
            id: layoutLogin
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            anchors.margins: 3
            spacing: 3

            TextField {
                id: usernameField
                textColor: "black"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: "Username"
            }

            TextField {
                id: passwordField
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                placeholderText: "Password"
                echoMode: TextInput.Password
                textColor: "black"
            }

            Button {
                id: proccessButton
                text: "Login"
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                onClicked: login.test()

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The full example can be found at the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/46854262)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the property name should be text.
Try this:

```
login_u = login->property("text").toString();
password_u = password->property("text").toString();
```

I realized that you are getting the values in the constructor of the Login class.
It should be obtained at the time of the call of test().

```
void Login::test()
{
    QQuickItem *object = m_view->rootObject();
    QObject *login = object->findChild<QObject*>("login");
    QObject *password = object->findChild<QObject*>("password");
    login_u = login->property("text").toString();
    password_u = password->property("text").toString();

    qDebug() << "user:" << login_u;
    qDebug() << "password" << password_u;
}
```

It worked here